# Getting image from UIBarButtonSystemItem icons

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have found several posts that hit all around this but none that really address it. I have a UIToolBar setup and want to use systemicons with it.  I setup the toolbar and setup my IBOutlets using the storyboard.  Right now, I have two items on the toolbar and want to use the system icons for the buttons.  The only way I have found to do this seems to be to programmatically create the buttons.  It would seem that there should be a way from the storyboard editor to set the buttons image to one of the standard system images enumerated in the UIBarButtonItem class reference.  Do I have to programmatically alloc and init the toolbar items to get a systemicon on it?  Even a convertsystemitem to UIimage type of method would be ok.  Something where I could do self.loadImageBarButton.image= UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera;  or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give from `storyBoard` also.Select the `barButtonItem` which added in `storyBoard`.Go `Attribute Inspector -> Idenifier` as shown in image and select appropriate `Identifier`

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Works perfect.  I was looking under image and it just lets you load one of your own.

Comment: Can't for another minute.  LOL

Comment: what do you mean?Not understand?

Comment: Someone posted (and then removed) a message telling me to mark the answer.  But we have to wait for a couple of minutes after the post before we can mark the answer as correct.